# "Java.util.NoSuchElement" when trying to do unit test

Tags: java

I want to create a unit test for my nim game that enters a number through the input stream and then get a result back. However, I keep on getting this error messaging saying java.util.NoSuchElement

Here is my code :

```
public void testTakeTurn() {
    System.out.println("takeTurn");

    String input = "3 2 1 ";
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
    ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    System.setIn(in);

    Pile p = new Pile(10);
    Player instance = new Player("Hecan");

    //case 1
    System.out.println("Testing remove 3 stones");
    input = "3 ";
    in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
    instance.takeTurn(p);
    int expectedPile = 7;
    int actualPile = p.getStones();
    assertEquals(expectedPile, actualPile, 0.0);

    //case2
    System.out.println("Testing remove 2 stones");
    input = "2 ";
    p.setStones(10);
    in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
    instance.takeTurn(p);
    expectedPile = 8;
    actualPile = p.getStones();
    assertEquals(expectedPile, actualPile, 0.0);

    //case3
    System.out.println("Testing remove 1 stones");
    input = "1 ";
    p.setStones(10);
    in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
    instance.takeTurn(p);
    expectedPile = 9;
    actualPile = p.getStones();
    assertEquals(expectedPile, actualPile, 0.0);
```

Comment: You need to provide the component you're trying to test and the test itself.

Comment: Could you please add more detail to your question? Any code would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Thank you for adding code to your post.  That is *essential*!  2) Of the code you've added ... which line number is giving you `java.util.NoSuchElement`?  There should be a "stack traceback", and you should be able to get the line# from the traceback.  Please update your post and show us the offending line.

Comment: The thing work if I comment out  case3, java is saying that line the line "instance.takeTurn(p);" in case 3 is giving me the error

Comment: It could be an issue with the code that you are trying to test. We don't know what `instance.takeTurn(p)` is actually doing.